# Is there a way to run both Apache and IIS on same machine

Tags: apache, iis

I am currently running Apache on Amazon Servers(Windows Server 2016).
Apache comes preinstalled running on default port 80. There are applications currently listening to this port.

I have IIS installed, however i am unable to host any site that would utilize the same port 80 or 443.

Is there a way around this?

Comment: It is not possible to run both the server on the same port number. try to run the iis on different IP port and apache on different IP port. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/108387/apache-and-iis-side-by-side-both-listening-to-port-80-on-windows2003

Answer (score 0):

change the port for apache from 80 to other like 8080

Comment: Thats the thing, i want Apache to retain that port number, what i want is IIS to be able to listen on Port 80 and 443.